# how to use assets in an angular library

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

In a microfront end architecture project. I have generated an angular library in which I have declared some components that must use images

To this end, in the same library I have created an assets folder and in project.json I have added the following:

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "libs/layout/src/assets",
            "output": "assets"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

I have also tried this other variant

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "assets": ["libs/layout/src/assets"]
      }
    },
  ...
```

In the component template I try the following:

```
<img
    ngSrc="libs/layout/src/assets/logo.png"
    height="40"
    width="120"
    alt="Main-Logo"
  />
```

The above doesn't work. When I load the images in the browser I get 404

thanks for any ideas

Comment: you added assets in build only. you also need to add  "assets": ["libs/layout/src/assets"] in prod .

Comment: ngSrc="/assets/logo.png"

Comment: you do not need to specify full path, you need to start from /assets/logo.png

Comment: <img [src]="'assets/img/klogo.png'" alt="image">

Comment: thanks for answering. but it still doesn't work